# getting 'MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method' when trying to use admob in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, admob

`MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method zzc(Bundle) in MediationRewardedVideoAdListener
public class MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor SocialFeedTest.Android C:\Users\blain\source\repos\SocialFeedTest\SocialFeedTest\SocialFeedTest.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\ads\reward\mediation\MediationRewardedVideoAdListenerImplementor.java 4`

following this tutorial here https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/ . this is hard to diagnose for me because it doesn't break on a line number in my code it says the error is in auto generated code i do not understand. neither does it say there is a error in my code but it will not let me build it or emulate it.

heres my code

xamarin.forms

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SocialFeedTest.Control
{
public class AdMobView : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                   nameof(AdUnitId),
                   typeof(string),
                   typeof(AdMobView),
                   string.Empty);

    public string AdUnitId
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
        set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
    }
  }
}
```

android

renderer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SocialFeedTest.Control;
using SocialFeedTest.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]

namespace SocialFeedTest.Droid
{
   public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, AdView>
{
    public AdMobViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null)
            SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(AdView.AdUnitId))
            Control.AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId;
    }

    private AdView CreateAdView()
    {
        var adView = new AdView(Context)
        {
            AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
            AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId
        };

        adView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

        return adView;
    }
    } 
}
```

main activity

```
   using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace SocialFeedTest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SocialFeedTest", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges =                   ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "ca-app-pub-5184019642309342~9928782520");
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[]  grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
  }
}
```

ios

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using Google.MobileAds;
using SocialFeedTest.Control;
using SocialFeedTest.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace SocialFeedTest.iOS
{

   public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, BannerView>
   {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(CreateBannerView());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(BannerView.AdUnitId))
            Control.AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId;
    }

    private BannerView CreateBannerView()
    {
        var bannerView = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait)
        {
            AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId,
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };

        bannerView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());

        Request GetRequest()
        {
            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            return request;
        }

        return bannerView;
    }

    private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
    {
        var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
        foreach (var window in windows)
        {
            if (window.RootViewController != null)
            {
                return window.RootViewController;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
  }

}
main

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace SocialFeedTest.iOS
{
   public class Application
    {
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using that version there are going to be compile warnings because it is not updated for the SDK change in ads from google.
Your manifest now should have this.

meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"

I suggest to use the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite if you only want ads.

You can see this [link](http://www.geojorgx.com/programacion/admob-the-easy-way/) for how to do it.

Comment: thanks it works with no build errors. but now it shows up as invisible

Comment: In debug mode it takes some time to appear, usually there should show as test banners, remember to set the manifest correctly according to the new SDK

Comment: also is there a way to do it with firebase. im using firebase as a backend and would like there analytics

Comment: Yes you can add Firebase Analitycs http://www.geojorgx.com/programacion/firebase